# Kendo React Editor how to set up text colors in HEX format instead of rgba

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-react-ui

I am using Kendo React Editor and when I am sending my colorized text to backend it comes with rgba color format:

`<span style="color: rgba(67, 113, 196, 1);">test</span>`

Is there any way to set it to HEX?

I haven't found anything helpful at Telerik's forums

Thank you